# Excel VBA adding lines to a word document table

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I'm trying to find a way to add lines and information to a prebuilt table in a word document. The table is right now only two lines. The headers and a blank line (2 Columns). How would I go about adding new lines of data to this table. I've tried with bookmarks but I have been unable to get the code to work.

I would give a sample of code but my code just fails so I don't think it would help.

I need to be able to loop through a 2-D array and insert new rows with information from the 2-D array for each time it loops.

Comment: Even if it doesn't work, posting your code is important to getting a good answer.  Your code sample often helps to define more clearly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567441/extract-data-from-word-document-to-an-excel-spreadsheet/3611739#3611739 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550959/excel-macro-pasting-text-from-excel-in-word-header/5555442#5555442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic syntax for inserting data into a pre-existing table in Word, from VBA in Excel:

```
Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = GetObject("path to my word document")

With doc.Tables(IndexNumberOfTableYouWant)
  .Cell(DesiredRow, 1).Range.Text = "my column 1 information"
  .Cell(DesiredRow, 2).Range.Text = "my column 2 information"
End With
```

As long as the proper number of columns is predefined, you can just keep adding rows by incrementing the `DesiredRow` variable, and Word will append those rows to the table automatically.