# Opening a word doc from excel, print a selection and a string on the same page

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database with word docs. The filenames are like 000001, 000002......

I have successfully written a macro that opens these documents, makes a selection until a value is found, print this selection and then close the document again and move on to the next. (see code below )

There is one thing I want to do extra, but I can't figure it out. I want the word "End" printed under this selection (on the same page). But I want to do this without making any change in the documents.
[image]

I don't want to change the documents because the value that needs to be printed with the selection comes from an userform textbox and is different every time. But if someone can help me, you can give an example with the word end

Added a picture above off what im looking for

this is my code now:

```
Dim i As Long, wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object, wdRng As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  For i = 1 To 9
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("\\path\" & Format(i, "000000") & ".NET", False, True, False)
With wdDoc
  Set wdRng = .Range(0, 0)
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .Text = "ENDLIST"
      .Forward = True
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchCase = True
      .Execute
    End With
    If .Find.found = True Then
      wdRng.End = .Duplicate.Start
      wdRng.Select
      wdDoc.PrintOut , Range:=1
    End If
  End With
  .Close False
End With
  Next
  .Quit
End With
Set wdRng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Is this possible, and if it is can someone please help me going

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is adding a footer, print, and then remove the footer.

Comment: That indeed sounds doable, I will try to find something like that. I'll let you know if I can make it work

Comment: I have found the following but I am not sure how to process it into my code, anyone any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550959/pasting-text-from-excel-in-word-header

Comment: I've managed to add a footer with my code. However, because I print a selection in my code the footer is not printed.

Comment: Why can't you change the document if you're closing it without saving?

Comment: This is completely true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out myself. The code below will open the word file, will add the information at the beginning of the doc, make a selection from the beginning until a word is found, print this selection and then close the word file again.

Couldn't figure out how to get it after the selection, like shown in the picture of the question. But the place didn't really matter as long as the needed information was on the paper and it looked neat.

```
Sub test()


Dim i As Long, wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object, wdRng As Object, wRng As Object
Dim BEGINNING_OF_STORY
Dim MOVE_SELECTION

BEGINNING_OF_STORY = 6

MOVE_SELECTION = 0

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  For i = 1 To 2
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("M:\" & Format(i, "000") & ".docx")
    With .Selection
    .Font.Bold = True
    .HomeKey BEGINNING_OF_STORY, MOVE_SELECTION
    .Font.Size = "25"
    .TypeText ("information" & vbCrLf)
    End With
    With wdDoc
      Set wdRng = .Range(0, 0)
      With .Range
        With .Find
          .Text = "DEF"
          .Forward = True
          .MatchWholeWord = True
          .MatchCase = True
          .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.found = True Then
          wdRng.End = .Duplicate.Start
          wdRng.Select
          wdDoc.PrintOut , Range:=1
        End If
      End With
      .Close False
    End With
  Next
  .Quit
End With
Set wdRng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Fitted my own needs, hope someone else can work with this sometimes too