# Why is this macro so slow?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

This macro opens a Word document (letter with merge fields as placeholders) and performs a mail merge to fill in the letter's sender information. It also prompts the user for custom values to fill in the addressee's name and address (FILLIN, not MERGE fields).

The sender's information is stored in an Excel spreadsheet. The first prompt is for the login ID, which is unique to each sender.  The macro works, but inefficiently. It takes several seconds to open the .docx and while the cursor is spinning, the user doesn't know what's going on. I added a message box, telling them to be patient, blah blah. Is there a way to make the .docx document open faster?  Just FYI, I built this macro from pieces of other code I found here on this website. I'm not an expert at VBA...  :(

```
 Sub Letter()
Dim wrdObj As Object, wrdDoc As Object
Dim strFile As String, myKey As String
Dim mySource As String: mySource = C:\LetterMemoDB.xls"

Set wrdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
myKey = InputBox("Enter sender's login ID (e.g., jtorres or b324):")
MsgBox ("Please wait a moment. If the template doesn't automatically open, go to the Word icon in the taskbar and open it from there. ")
With wrdObj
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        Set wrdDoc = .Documents.Open("C:\NewLetterTemplate.docx", False, True, False, , , , , , , , False)
        With wrdDoc
            With .MailMerge
                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                .OpenDataSource Name:=mySource, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                  LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
                  "Data Source=mySource;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
                  SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [All_Users$] WHERE LoginID = '" & myKey & "'"
                .Execute Pause:=True
            End With
    .Close 0
        End With
    .Activate
End With
Set wrdDoc = Nothing: Set wrdObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

The spreadsheet looks like this:
[image]

UPDATE:
From Charles Kenyon's suggestion, I changed the code as shown below, but now I'm getting prompted for input twice to populate the FILLIN fields.

```
Sub Letter_V2()
Dim myKey As String
Dim mySource As String: mySource = "C:\LetterMemoDB.xls"

Documents.Add Template:="C:\ NewLetterTemplate.docx", NewTemplate:=False
 myKey = InputBox("Enter sender's login ID (e.g., jtorres or b324):")
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        .OpenDataSource Name:=mySource, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
          LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
          "Data Source=mySource;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
          SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [All_Users$] WHERE LoginID = '" & myKey & "'"
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

-- UPDATE on 6/4/2021 - I changed the macro again. Added a reference to the Word Object Library for Office 2016 and change the code as follows.  Maybe I'm still not understanding "early binding" vs "late binding."

```
Option Explicit

Sub Letter()
Dim wrdObj As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim excObj As Excel.Application
Dim strFile As String, myKey As String
Dim mySource As String: mySource = "C:\LetterMemoDB.xls"

Set wrdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set excObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

myKey = InputBox("Enter sender's login ID (e.g., jtorres or b324):")
'MsgBox ("Please wait a moment. If the template doesn't automatically open, go to the Word icon in the taskbar and open it from there. ")
With wrdObj
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        Set wrdDoc = .Documents.Open("C:\NewLetterTemplate.docx", False, True, False, , , , , , , , False)
        With wrdDoc
            With .MailMerge
                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                .OpenDataSource Name:=mySource, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                  LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
                  "Data Source=mySource;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
                  SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [All_Users$] WHERE LoginID = '" & myKey & "'"
                .Execute Pause:=True
            End With
    .Close 0
        End With
    .Activate
End With
Set wrdDoc = Nothing: Set wrdObj = Nothing
Close excObj
Set excObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You are opening a Word document and attaching the source. This will never be instantaneous. It would operate faster if run from Word with Word open already.

Comment: Thank you Charles Kenyon.  Please see update in main post. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is slow because you're using late binding. According to MS, it would run twice as fast with early binding.

Comment: ^^^^^[this may prove useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697413/late-binding-vs-early-binding-with-embedded-word-documents)

Comment: I added a reference to the Word Object Library and put the macro in its own module, starting it with "Option Explicit".  I changed from 
Dim wrdObj As Object, wrdDoc As Object to

Dim wrdObj As Word.Application 
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document

and Set wrdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Still running super slow...   Any other ideas?