# Extract Data from PDF and Add to Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to extract the data from a PDF document into a worksheet. The PDFs show and text can be manually copied and pasted into the Excel document.

I am currently doing this through SendKeys and it is not working. I get an error when I try to paste the data from the PDF document. Why is my paste not working? If I paste after the macro has stopped running it pastes as normal.

```
Dim myPath As String, myExt As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim openPDF As Object
'Dim pasteData As MSForms.DataObject
Dim fCell As Range

'Set pasteData = New MSForms.DataObject
Set ws = Sheets("DATA")
If ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then Range("A3:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

myExt = "\*.pdf"
'When Scan Receipts Button Pressed Scan the selected folder/s for receipts
For Each fCell In Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    myPath = Dir(fCell.Value & myExt)
    Do While myPath <> ""
        myPath = fCell.Value & "\" & myPath
        Set openPDF = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        openPDF.Open (myPath)
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
        SendKeys "^a"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
        SendKeys "^c"
        'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
        ws.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        'pasteData.GetFromClipboard

        'ws.Cells(3, 1) = pasteData.GetText
        Exit Sub

        myPath = Dir
    Loop

Next fCell
```

Comment: As someone who came across this and did a little more searching I found this to be [a valid reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302445/convert-pdf-to-word-doc-using-excel-vba-code#) as an alternate method.

Answer (score 22):

You can open the PDF file and extract its contents using the Adobe library (which I believe you can download from Adobe as part of the SDK, but it comes with certain versions of Acrobat as well)

Make sure to add the Library to your references too (On my machine it is the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library, but not sure if that is the newest version)

Even with the Adobe library it is not trivial (you'll need to add your own error-trapping etc):

```
Function getTextFromPDF(ByVal strFilename As String) As String
   Dim objAVDoc As New AcroAVDoc
   Dim objPDDoc As New AcroPDDoc
   Dim objPage As AcroPDPage
   Dim objSelection As AcroPDTextSelect
   Dim objHighlight As AcroHiliteList
   Dim pageNum As Long
   Dim strText As String

   strText = ""
   If (objAvDoc.Open(strFilename, "") Then
      Set objPDDoc = objAVDoc.GetPDDoc
      For pageNum = 0 To objPDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
         Set objPage = objPDDoc.AcquirePage(pageNum)
         Set objHighlight = New AcroHiliteList
         objHighlight.Add 0, 10000 ' Adjust this up if it's not getting all the text on the page
         Set objSelection = objPage.CreatePageHilite(objHighlight)

         If Not objSelection Is Nothing Then
            For tCount = 0 To objSelection.GetNumText - 1
               strText = strText & objSelection.GetText(tCount)
            Next tCount
         End If
      Next pageNum
      objAVDoc.Close 1
   End If

   getTextFromPDF = strText

End Function
```

What this does is essentially the same thing you are trying to do - only using Adobe's own library.  It's going through the PDF one page at a time, highlighting all of the text on the page, then dropping it (one text element at a time) into a string.

Keep in mind what you get from this could be full of all kinds of non-printing characters (line feeds, newlines, etc) that could even end up in the middle of what look like contiguous blocks of text, so you may need additional code to clean it up before you can use it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: the Adobe Library is definitely the way to go. Want to note that it can be more powerful than what you have displayed though in that it can get text from individuals blocks of text boxes or other objects, which may be more succinct / helpful (or not) to the OP than just grabbing all text on page

Comment: Fantastic answer!  On my Excel setup I had to add a reference library called "Adobe" to get this to work.  By the way, you have a typo on the line `If (objAvDoc.Open(strFilename, "")`.  It should be `If (objAvDoc.Open(strFilename, ""))`.  If `Option Explicit` is used (as it should be), you will also need to add this line to your variables block:  `Dim tCount As Long`.  Thanks @leowyn for this resource!

Comment: It looks like the SDK is only available through license with Adobe. Is there a way to get it without having to pay $$$$ for the professional version?

Comment: Small typo: If (objAvDoc.Open(strFilename, "") Then >> If objAvDoc.Open(strFilename, "") Then - but otherwise works like a charm, no commercials needed. No additional installation is needed, SDK now arrives with Reader, from the looks of it, only need to add "Acrobat" to the Tools | References in the VBA project.

Comment: You need to have Adobe Acrobat Pro, Adobe Reader won't work.

Comment: Does anyone know how you would implement this function into a VBA code?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old issue but I just had to do this for a project at work, and I am very surprised that nobody has thought of this solution yet:
**Just open the .pdf with Microsoft word.**

The code is a lot easier to work with when you are trying to extract data from a .docx because it opens in Microsoft Word. Excel and Word play well together because they are both Microsoft programs. In my case, the file of question *had* to be a .pdf file. Here's the solution I came up with:

1. Choose the default program to open .pdf files to be Microsoft Word
2. The first time you open a .pdf file with word, a dialogue box pops up claiming word will need to convert the .pdf into a .docx file. Click the check box in the bottom left stating "do not show this message again" and then click OK.
3. Create a macro that extracts data from a .docx file. I used [MikeD's Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567441/extract-data-from-word-document-to-an-excel-spreadsheet) as a resource for this.
4. Tinker around with the MoveDown, MoveRight, and Find.Execute methods to fit the need of your task.

Yes you could just convert the .pdf file to a .docx file but this is a much simpler solution in my opinion.

Edit [30-Nov-2023]: Looking back on this old project, it's worth mentioning a few points for anyone doing this themselves:

1. Keep in mind the ramifications of changing the default program to Word for opening .PDFs (i.e. you will have to manually specify to open using different software every time)
2. I used the vba visibility function to prevent word from opening on the desktop for the user to see. This made the code run significantly faster, however the trade-off is that the user has no idea what was going on in the background. I ended up creating a loading bar in excel to help alleviate that.
3. It is *imperative* that the first time you run this code on the user's machine, you select the option to convert to .pdf and then select "do not show again", especially if you are using the visibility command. In fact I am 99% sure that if you hide the word window using visibility and then don't select that checkbox, it will break everything or just hang waiting for a response that it will never get.

Things are much more well documented these days than in 2019 so that edit might not have been to helpful to a lot of you guys but I just want to see people succeed so sue me!

Comment: I am getting an error that the PDF exceeds the maximal page size supported by word. Do you know anyway around this?

Comment: No Way.... Wth... how did I not know this... I've been messing around for years thinking you needed 'acrobatpro', 'other software', or 'sketchy online sites' to convert a pdf to word docx. While I still think using the Acobat library is a better method, you just stuck a huge tool in my box. I'm blown away I haven't known about this for years. do you know which is the first version of word to support this?

Comment: @CameronCritchlow I'm not familiar with the first version of word to support this, and to be honest I'm surprised it does. I ended up finding out about this as a co-op in college so I'm by no means an expert in any of this. I was surprised to see that method worked out as well as it did. Hope it comes in handy for you one day too!

Answer (score 4):

Over time, I have found that extracting text from PDFs in a structured format is tough business. However if you are looking for an easy solution, you might want to consider [XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) tool `pdftotext`.

Pseudocode to extract the text would include:

1. Using `SHELL` VBA statement to extract the text from PDF to a temporary file using [XPDF](http://www.experts-exchange.com/videos/217/Xpdf-Convert-PDF-Files-to-Plain-Text-Files-Part-3.html)
2. Using sequential file read statements to read the temporary file contents into a string
3. Pasting the string into Excel

Simplified example below:

```
    Sub ReadIntoExcel(PDFName As String)
        'Convert PDF to text
        Shell "C:\Utils\pdftotext.exe -layout " & PDFName & " tempfile.txt"

        'Read in the text file and write to Excel
        Dim TextLine as String
        Dim RowNumber as Integer
        Dim F1 as Integer
        RowNumber = 1
        F1 = Freefile()
        Open "tempfile.txt" for Input as #F1
            While Not EOF(#F1)
                Line Input #F1, TextLine
                ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets(1).Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = TextLine
                RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
            Wend
        Close #F1
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I do not prefer to rely on external libraries and/or other programs, I have extended your solution so that it works.
The actual change here is using the *GetFromClipboard* function instead of *Paste* which is mainly used to paste a range of cells.
Of course, the downside is that the user must not change focus or intervene during the whole process.

```
Dim pathPDF As String, textPDF As String
Dim openPDF As Object
Dim objPDF As MsForms.DataObject

pathPDF = "C:\some\path\data.pdf"
Set openPDF = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
openPDF.Open (pathPDF)
'TIME TO WAIT BEFORE/AFTER COPY AND PASTE SENDKEYS
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
SendKeys "^a"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
SendKeys "^c"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")

AppActivate ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption
objPDF.GetFromClipboard
textPDF = objPDF.GetText(1)
MsgBox textPDF
```

If you're interested see my project in [github](https://github.com/decade62/pdf2excel-vba).

Comment: This is the solution I generally use when I'm forced to use copy and paste. Despite it being considered bad form, I've found it to be incredibly reliable. I make sure windows are in specified locations then check pixels on the screen to check for loadedness:

Comment: `Public Function getScreenPixel(x As Long, y As Long) As Variant` </br>
 `Dim desktopDC As LongPtr: desktopDC = GetDC(0)` </br>
 `Dim memDC     As LongPtr: memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(desktopDC)` </br>
 `Dim memBMP    As LongPtr: memBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(desktopDC, 1, 1)` </br>
 `If SelectObject(memDC, memBMP) <> 0 And BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, desktopDC, x, y, srccopy) <> 0 Then` </br>
  `getScreenPixel = GetPixel(memDC, 0, 0)` </br>
 `End If` </br>
 `DeleteObject memBMP` </br>
 `DeleteDC memDC` </br>
`End Function` </br>

Comment: Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long

Comment: Private Declare PtrSafe Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestDC As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As LongPtr, ByVal xSrc As Long, ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long

Answer (score 1):

Copying and pasting by user interactions emulation could be not reliable (for example, popup appears and it switches the focus). You may be interested in trying the commercial [ByteScout PDF Extractor SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) that is specifically designed to extract data from PDF and it works from VBA. It is also capable of extracting data from invoices and tables as CSV using [VB code](https://github.com/bytescout/ByteScout-SDK-SourceCode/blob/master/PDF%20Extractor%20SDK/Find%20Table%20And%20Extract%20As%20CSV/VBScript/FindTableAndExtractAsCSV.vbs).

Here is the VBA code for Excel to extract text from given locations and save them into cells in the `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Create TextExtractor object
' Set extractor = CreateObject("Bytescout.PDFExtractor.TextExtractor")
Dim extractor As New Bytescout_PDFExtractor.TextExtractor

extractor.RegistrationName = "demo"
extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo"

' Load sample PDF document
extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile ("c:\sample1.pdf")

' Get page count
pageCount = extractor.GetPageCount()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TxtRng  As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = 0 To pageCount - 1
            RectLeft = 10
            RectTop = 10
            RectWidth = 100
            RectHeight = 100

            ' check the same text is extracted from returned coordinates
            extractor.SetExtractionArea RectLeft, RectTop, RectWidth, RectHeight
            ' extract text from given area
            extractedText = extractor.GetTextFromPage(i)

            ' insert rows
            ' Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
            ' write cell value
             Set TxtRng = ws.Range("A" & CStr(i + 2))
             TxtRng.Value = extractedText

Next

Set extractor = Nothing


End Sub
```

*Disclosure: I am related to ByteScout*

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bytescout PDF Extractor SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) is a good option. It is cheap and gives plenty of PDF related functionality. One of the answers above points to the dead page Bytescout on GitHub. I am providing a relevant working sample to extract table from PDF. You may use it to export in any format.

```
Set extractor = CreateObject("Bytescout.PDFExtractor.StructuredExtractor")

extractor.RegistrationName = "demo"
extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo"

' Load sample PDF document
extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile "../../sample3.pdf"

For ipage = 0 To extractor.GetPageCount() - 1 

    ' starting extraction from page #"
    extractor.PrepareStructure ipage

    rowCount = extractor.GetRowCount(ipage)

    For row = 0 To rowCount - 1 
        columnCount = extractor.GetColumnCount(ipage, row)

        For col = 0 To columnCount-1
            WScript.Echo "Cell at page #" +CStr(ipage) + ", row=" & CStr(row) & ", column=" & _
                CStr(col) & vbCRLF & extractor.GetCellValue(ipage, row, col)
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Many more samples available here: https://github.com/bytescout/pdf-extractor-sdk-samples

Answer (score 0):

To improve the solution of Slinky Sloth I had to add this beforere get from clipboard :

```
Set objPDF = New MSForms.DataObject
```

Sadly it didn't worked for a pdf of 10 pages.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't seem to work with the Adobe Type library.  As soon as it gets to Open, I get a 429 error.  Acrobat works fine though...