# Importing from fillable PDF data to MS Access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I do have more than 100 pdf files weekly filled that I have to run report on them. PDFs have same format, readable. All I want is to collect somehow all the data to access database. I do not have sharepoint and not using LiveCycle. I`m not bad at vba but I really could not think on how I would approach this. So I hope someone outthere had to go through it?

Comment: This question is too broad. There are multiple different kinds of fillable PDFs (mainly AcroForms and XFAs), and importing depends on many factors.

Comment: This should get you close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270247/vba-extract-data-from-pdf-and-add-to-worksheet