# How to extract data from Word File to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a folder with over 1000+ word files with same structure (each of the file consists of a table). Like this:-

| Type     | Apple    |
| Price    | $  5     |

I have to extract data from all these word files to in a spreadsheet excel. So far, I only copy the path of all files in the first column.

Is there any formulas or VBA can be used? Many thanks

I tried to use the VBA provided in [xtract Data from Word Document to an Excel SpreadSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567441/extract-data-from-word-document-to-an-excel-spreadsheet), but it is only applicable to a single file.

Comment: The post, you refer to, is interpreting a wordfile and getting information out of it. If you are about to do this for more than a thousand files, you might wait a very long time for this thing to finish. If you have a WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on your computer, you might try to use the general structure of a wordfile (being some zipped directory and file structure) and use a tool like `zgrep` for getting your information. (However, I don't have any experience in that matter, it's just a direction I'm pointing you to.)

Comment: I have unzipped a wordfile, containing just the information you provided. I got a directory, containing a file "content.xml", having a structure, where the content could be found using ±`/document-content/body/text/p` as an XPath expression. So, if you find a way to launch an XPath expression in a zipped directory, containing some XML file, you might have a very fast result for your question.